# How do I compare online products accurately based on their title?

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

I want to increase the accuracy of product comparison engine [Khareeda](http://www.khareeda.com)

The current problem is it is based on textual comparison only so even a space or slight changes would make the products appear as distinct and get excluded from comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use full text search when querying data from db.

Comment: Queering data??

Comment: I think you might have missed what I was getting at.  **Queering** data?

Comment: fixed, sorry :)